# How many ways to pick 5 days without taking Consecutives in November

Tags: combinatorics

I would like to participate in irregular project in a company and can choose my five days to commute to the HQ of the company in November ($30$ days).

However I would like to opt out of the options which involve going to HQ $2$ consecutive days in a row.

Then how many options do I have?

Comment: November actually has $30$ days.

Comment: Oh right 30days in Nov

Comment: Are you avoiding weekends?

Comment: At the risk of complicating things, are all $30$ days available or just weekdays?

Comment: All 30days available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We will arrange $25$ blue balls and $5$ green balls in a row.

Place $25$ blue balls in a row.  This creates $26$ spaces, $24$ between successive blue balls and two at the ends of the row.  To ensure that no two green balls are consecutive, we must choose $5$ of these $26$ spaces in which to insert a green ball.  Now, number the balls from $1$ to $30$ from left to right.  The numbers on the green balls are the dates on which you commute to work.  Therefore, there are $\binom{26}{5}$ possible schedules.